# Build the application: Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Unrecognized alias: layout.center

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

After the build of the application and its subsequent launch, an error message appeared

```
Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Unrecognized alias: layout.center
```

This has often happened. For example, for the `Ext.window.MessageBox` or `Ext.data.proxy.Ajax` class.

That is, for proper assembly, you need to specify all the classes that are used in the code in the `requires` sections.

But why this problem has appeared for `layout.center`? There are other layouts nearby. For example, `hbox`. And nowhere did I prescribe it in `requires` it.

Why do such errors appear then disappear?

Also, how to make these errors appear during the development of the watch? To exterminate them in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So you are using [`layout:'center'`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.layout.container.Center.html) somewhere, without adding the layout to the requires. What do you mean, "such errors appear, then disappear"? They can only disappear once you add `'Ext.layout.container.Center'` to your requires section and recompile.

That this is not a problem with `hbox` for you, can only mean that you require one of `Ext.window.MessageBox`, `Ext.toolbar.Toolbar`, `Ext.grid.column.Column`, `Ext.form.Basic`, `Ext.form.Panel`, `Ext.grid.RowEditor` in a view that is loaded before you use `layout:'hbox'` - these Sencha components already have `Ext.layout.container.HBox` somewhere in their `requires` tree (e.g. RowEditor requires formpanel, formpanel requires form.Basic, form.Basic requires MessageBox, MessageBox requires HBox layout).

There is no possibility to show such errors during development, which is why I developed the habit to err on the side of caution, requiring `hbox` and `vbox` from my main Application.js file and nearly automatically adding the requires whenever I use another layout or xtype.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer cleared up a lot. Now it is clear why sometimes there is no error on the vbox.