# error Unrecognized alias when i try use layout: "border"

Tags: javascript, extjs, syntax-error, alias, panel

I try to create panel element with layout:'border' and get next error:**Unrecognized alias: layout.border**
I try to find any answer, but all I could find similar to the answer is the following discussion [Unrecognized alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43475228/build-the-application-error-ext-createbyalias-unrecognized-alias-layout-cen). The solution given in the article did not help me, unfortunately, please tell me how to fix this error
This is are link to my Fiddle [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3o38&view/editor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the "Ext.layout.container.Border" layout is not available in Ext JS Modern Toolkit. It is available in the Classic Toolkit instead.In the Modern Toolkit, the equivalent layout for creating a border layout is "Ext.layout.Box". You can update your code to use the "box" layout instead. Here's the modified code:

```
Ext.define("ModernApp.view.customLayout.CustomLayoutView", {
  extend: "Ext.panel.Panel",
  alias: "widget.custom",
  requires: ["Ext.layout.Box"], // Update the layout requirement
  layout: "box", // Use 'box' layout instead of 'border'
  items: [{
         ...
      }],
});
```